# Default implementation of supertrait

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait, `MyGoodTrait`, with the function `label(&self) -> &str`. I want every implementor of `MyGoodTrait` to also implement `Display` and `FromStr`. However, I do not necessarily need `Display` and `FromStr` to be supertraits of `MyGoodTrait`. I would rather somehow have a default implementation of `Display` and `FromStr`, which will internally use the `label` function from `MyGoodTrait`. That way, every implementor of `MyGoodTrait` will get `Display` and `FromStr` "for free", as if there was a default implementation for those traits.

Here is an example that is similar to what I want to do, but it does not compile:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

pub trait MyGoodTrait {
    fn new() -> Self;

    fn label(&self) -> &'static str;
}

impl FromStr for dyn MyGoodTrait {
    type Err = String;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(Self::new())
    }
}

pub struct A {}

impl MyGoodTrait for A {

    fn new() -> Self {
        A{}
    }
    fn label(&self) -> &'static str {
        "A"
    }
}

pub struct B {}

impl MyGoodTrait for B {

    fn new() -> Self {
        B{}
    }
    fn label(&self) -> &'static str {
        "B"
    }
}

// In this hypothetical, A and B now both have `fmt` and `from_str` functions
```

Is there a way to write this default implementation of `Display` and `FromStr`, such that I do not have to duplicate the code for each struct that implements `MyGoodTrait`?

Note: My actual use case is that I have a trait which has `serde::se::Serialize` and `serde::de::Deserialize` as supertraits. The implementors of my trait will be used as keys in a map, and I will serialize the map to JSON, so I need the implementors to be serialized to Strings. So this may be an example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I don't understand the dependencies here. What you're literally asking is impossible. For the "default" implementation of `Display` to make sense, you'd have to have a type that implements `MyTrait` *but not* `Display` -- which isn't possible because `MyTrait` has `Display` as a supertrait!

Comment: Ok, I understand what I did wrong here. I was thinking of traits in terms of inheritance, which is not quite right. I don't need `Display` to be a super trait of `MyGoodTrait`, I just want every struct that implements `MyGoodTrait` to also get `Display` for "free", so to speak. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: You can't.

---

You can't implement `FromStr` for `dyn SomeTrait` because it has a method that returns a `Result<Self, _>`, hence you can only implement it for types whose size are know at compile time, which is not the case of trait objects.

What you would really want is

```rust
impl<T: MyGoodTrait> FromStr for T
```

But now you might violate the orphan rule. As the compiler explains:

> Implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which is it implemented is local.
>   Only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter.

But you could do it if `FromStr` was a local trait instead:

```
/// Copy of `std::str::FromStr`
trait Foo: Sized {
    type Err;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err>;
}

impl<T: MyGoodTrait> Foo for T {
    type Err = String;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(Self::new())
    }
}
```

Or you could implement it for any specific local type:

```
impl FromStr for A {
    type Err = String;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(Self::new())
    }
}
```